# Error: "relation "django_comments" does not exist"

Tags: django, django-users

I'm trying to delete users from the admin and get this error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/users/neverlateuser/
    relation "django_comments" does not exist
    LINE 1: ..._admin", "users_neverlateuser"."date_joined" FROM "django_co...
```

but I don't have the comments installed, I don't have `django.contrib.comments`. I get this error only on the live server but not on the local host- there I can delete users with no problem. Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue. I am facing the exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by adding `django.contrib.comments` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. I don't think this is a must, but I guess I used comments before and removed it later from the project (long-term project). So add it and run syncdb plus migrate.

Answer (score 0):

may be the owner of the table is changed on the production server. if you are using postgresql , you can edit the table with pgadmin3 to see who is the actual owner of the table. the same thing exit with mysql too.